# Asked to show that $(p \land (q \oplus r))$ and $(p \oplus q) \land (p \oplus r)$ are logically equivalent, but truth tables don't match.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

> Show that $(p \land (q \oplus r))$ and $(p \oplus q) \land (p \oplus r)$ are logically equivalent.

Yet I don't see how they are logically equivalent. I try to use the truth table and they do not match. Am I missing something? or how should I prove they are not logically equivalent except using truth table?

Thanks.

Comment: Check the truth table : if they "do not match" the formulas are **not** equivalent.

Comment: If the truth tables are not the same then they can't be logically equivalent.

Comment: I am 100% sure this is the question.

Comment: The first one is equivalent to $(p \land q) \oplus (p \land r)$, though. So maybe a typo somewhere?

Answer (score 5):

The two expressions are not equivalent. Take $p=0,q=r=1$. They give different values.

Comment: So, can I say because their truth values are different, they are not equivalent?

Comment: Yes, that is right. They should generate the same output for the same input, otherwise they are not equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Think about it. *How* could you define equivalence for logical expressions?

A reasonable guess would be
$$f(a_1,\dots,a_n) \equiv g(a_1,\dots,a_n) \iff \forall (a_1,\dots,a_n) \ \ f(a_1,\dots,a_n) = g(a_1,\dots,a_n).$$

The condition above is simply stating that the truth tables must match.

Answer (score 0):

Just because one is asked to show something does not mean that one will always be able to do so. One should keep in mind that a question might be in error or it might be posed as a challenge to find what is wrong with it.

If the truth tables do not match, as the OP discovered, then these formulas are not logically equivalent. A counterexample would be any row or valuation for $p$, $q$ and $r$ where the formulas do not have the same truth value.

To get an intuitive feel why these formulas should not be equivalent recall that [exclusive or](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or#Equivalences,_elimination,_and_introduction) requires that one and only one side of this connective be true, that is, if we have $p \oplus q$ then one of the sides must be true, $p \lor q$, but also only one of the sides must be true, $\neg(p \land q)$.

Consider $p \land (q \oplus r)$. For that to be true both conjuncts must be true. Therefore the left conjunct, $p$, must be true. To make the right conjunct, $q \oplus r$, true one and only one of $q$ and $r$ must be true. Let $q$ be true and $r$ be false.

Now consider, using those valuations, $(p \oplus q) \land (p \oplus r)$. We want this to be true to match the truth value of the other formula. The conjunction requires that both conjuncts be true. In particular, $p \oplus q$ must be true. But this cannot be true if both $p$ and $q$ are both true as the valuations require them to be. Since one of the conjuncts is false that means the conjunction itself is false.

We found a valuation, $p$ and $q$ are true and $r$ is false, where one formula is true and the other formula is false. This should have been a row in the truth tables where they do not match. Therefore, these formulas are not equivalent.